# Sample program in CCStudio

Tags: c, arm, embedded, microcontroller, texas-instruments

Could we do the sample program without having its Launchpad in **CCStudio** (For example, We can program the Microchip IDE without having the  PIC microcontroller connected)?

Answer (score 1):

Of course.  You can compile and link project without hardware.  You cannot if course load, run or debug it (unless you use a simulator).